# A point where the derivative is $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

> Let $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$, where $I$ is an interval and $a \in I$ such that $f'(a)= \infty$. Prove that there is a neighborhood $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$ such that $f$ is convex on $(a-\epsilon, a)$ and $f$ is concave on $(a, a+\epsilon)$.

I tried to use the definition of the derivative, but I only got that there is a left-neighborhood of $a$ where $f(x)< f(a)$ and a right-neighborhood of $a$ where $f(x)>f(a)$.

I suppose that the statement is false, but I couldn't construct an elementary counter example. Is there any?

Comment: Did you try the second derivative?

Comment: Depending on what $f(a)=\infty$ means, I think the statement might be true. Informally: If the function assumes an infinite value at some point, it must be increasing to the left and decreasing to the right of the point, that comes quite close to the definition of being convex/concave at those intervals.

Comment: @Henrik, it is $f'(a)=\infty$ not $f(a)=\infty.$ I.e. $f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \infty$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, yes, but apart from the definition, I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: Can you show f’ is increasing (so f’’ is positive) on $(a-\epsilon, a)?$

Comment: I am not sure. Why would $f'$ be (eventually) increasing left to $a$?

Comment: Can we assume f’ is continuous?

Comment: I think even with $f'$ continuous, and even $f$ double differentiable on $I - a$, the statement would still be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

The result is wrong. Look at

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-\sqrt{-x} + x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & x <0\\
0 & x=0\\
\sqrt{x} + x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)& x>0
\end{cases}$$

And prove that around zero the derivative is not monotonic on each side of zero.

Comment: But on $(-0.2,0)$, $f$ is convex. I think $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ instead of $\sin x$ works.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the typo! That was indeed $\sin 1/x$ that I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

This is false. If $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\Bbb R\setminus\{a\}$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)=\infty$ then it follows from the Mean Value Theorem that $f'(a)=\infty$, but $f'$ certainly need not be monotone on $(a-\epsilon,a)$.